# Solr Search for term with under certain price

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am working on an e-commerce app whose search is powered by Solr. How can I accomplish something like: 'DSLR under $600' gives me products that are found with DSLR and price is under $600?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene and Solr query parser support less than or equal to `(<=):`

```
?q=name:DSLR AND price:[* to 600]
```

*Note : Assuming your field is "name"*

This would give you the less than 600 dollars.

Square brackets `[ & ]` denote an inclusive range query that matches values including the upper and lower bound.

Curly brackets `{ & }` denote an exclusive range query that matches values between the upper and lower bounds, but excluding the upper and lower bounds themselves.

For more details please refer [Range Searches](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html)

Comment: Getting this, I will try this to implement. However, I believe I need to write my login in application to covert term like 'DSLR under $600' to ?q=name:DSLR AND price:[* to 600] or does solr can do it automatically.

Comment: I assumed that people will search for term "DSLR" and they will have range options to choose...like 0 - 100, 100 - 500 something like this and when they will select a option you will use the same in your solr range query...

Comment: in short yes...you have to either write a logic in your application to convert the term or You can opt for the range selection criteria for users

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
protocol://{solr-url}/solr/{collection-name}/select?
fq=name:DSLR
&fq=price:[0 TO 600]
&q=*:*
&wt=json
```

In my understanding
Using fq over q is recommended here.

Comment: how does it differ for fq or q!